# GPG error, signatures public key not available TRIED A LOT

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

*apt-get update* returns :

```
W: GPG error: http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: GPG error: http://deb.torproject.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EE8CBC9E886DDD89
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
```

I've tried many recommended solutions from old questions but nothing seems to help.

- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
  (with all the missing keys)
- I installed [lauchpad-getkeys](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/launchpad-getkeys-gets-proxy-support.html) which is supposed to restore keys automatically

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, I tried --recv-keys with no luck.

Comment: Please post the output of command `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5`

Comment: `Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.ux3Y2CVCoP --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always`  

(trimmed list of repositories)  

`gpg: keyblock resource /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xorg-edgers-ppa.gpg: resource limit
gpg: keyblock resource /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yktooo-ppa.gpg: resource limit
gpg: requesting key 437D05B5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Comment: @isomorphismes NOPE. That particular key `40976EAF437D05B5` is extremely stubborn and hard to fix, so Q 13065 only covers the cases that the OP has tried umpteen times anyway. This is as if you gave me a Pozidriv screwdriver when I need a Torx one. ;)

Comment: @syntaxerror ah ok. sorry.

Comment: @isomorphismes but I've just managed to fix this stubborn key here on my machine!! There were 5 `NO_PUBKEY` errors, 1 of which I had to fix manually, but 4 of which I was able to fix with the simple line `sudo apt-key update`. The latter line also covered the `40976EA...` key case. Mission completed. Note the essential albeit minor difference between `apt-*key* update` and `apt-*get* update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably affected by [bug 1263540](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540). I suggest you try:

1. sudo apt-get clean
2. sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.old
3. mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
4. Remove any 0 lenght files in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
5. sudo apt-get update

If it doesn't work restore /var/lib/apt/lists backed up in step 2.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540/comments/7)

Comment: Fixed it :) Not sure if following your steps helped, because I still had the same problem afterwards. What seems to have done it is deleting _yktooo-ppa.gpg_ in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d, even though it wasn't 0 length. I chose it because it came up earlier as mentionned above _resource limit gpg: keyblock resource /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yktooo-ppa.gpg_

Comment: I have added another repository and the error has returned. Looks like it's the same bug as you linked to :( Hope they fix it soon

Answer (score 3):

The `apt` present in Ubuntu is suffering from a [gpg resource limit bug in apt](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733028)

You can easily fix this going to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` and removing unused keys (usually from PPAs you don't use anymore) until get below 40 keys.

Then ran `sudo apt-get update`