# Cant update Ubuntu, neither using the terminal nor using the setting

Tags: updates, repository

I'm a total newbie to Linux as in Ubuntu, recently thought of switching over to Brave browser and thought of deleting MS Edge, since then I cant update (LTS 20.4)
instead of update, I get the revert option only[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WH5j.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GPG error, signatures public key not available TRIED A LOT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525416/gpg-error-signatures-public-key-not-available-tried-a-lot)

Comment: See the answer by @Kurt. FYI, the `&&` in your command indicates that you're actually chaining together two commands. Because it can be valuable as a new Linux user to understand what each command does, I suggest that you run these commands one-at-a-time. This also will let you review the output of the first command before starting the next one. Also, in the future if you need help, please don't post images of text. They are hard to work with. Instead, copy/paste the whole thing here and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for formatting

Answer (score 2):

The error actually tells you what is wrong:

The repository `https://packages.microsoft.com...` is not signed. The public key is not available.

When you installed Microsoft Edge, for some reason the public key was not added properly.

To get rid of this error you need to review the original steps you followed when you added the Microsoft Edge repos and see if you can get the public key added correctly.

Or, you can use a text editor to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Delete the offending line or comment it out by putting `#` in front of it.

Alternatively, there is a usually a GUI way to remove sources. Using the KDE desktop environment, the options are in Discover. In GNOME you can change sources in the Software Center.